# zhmakeindex is denied when to make Chinese index with imakeidx

Tags: indexing, makeindex

First an MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\imki@progdefault{zhmakeindex}
\makeatother

\makeindex


\begin{document}

    测试三角形\index{三角形}
    
    测试二次曲线\index{二次曲线}
    
    向量\index{向量}
    
    共线\index{共线}
    
    简比\index{简比}

    \printindex
\end{document}
```

As you see, I use [`zhmakeindex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/zhmakeindex) to make Chinese index with `imakeidx` as above. Before compiling the `tex` file, I download the `bin` file from [the link](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing/zhmakeindex/bin/darwin_x64) since when I input `uname -a` in the terminal on my Macbook Pro it produces the information as follows

```
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Jun 22 19:37:08 PDT 2021;
root:xnu-4903.278.70~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

and then add the `bin` file into the following folder where the `makeindex` locates

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin/
```

I compile the `tex` file by XeLaTeX with `-shell-escape` option, but it says

```
sh: /Library/TeX/texbin/zhmakeindex: Permission denied
```

and produces the index page on which the index entries are in occurrence order but not in Chinese pinyin alphabet order.

**So what's wrong or what I missed? Not install Go programming language on my Macbook, or something else?**

Comment: Did you assign executable permission?

Comment: @egreg No. And how to do that?

Comment: `sudo chmod a+x /Library/TeX/texbin/zhmakeindex`

Comment: @egreg According the [README](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing/zhmakeindex) of `zhmakeindex`, the Go language is needed, so should I install it before assigning executable permission?

Comment: You need Go to *compile* the program. Just set the permission and remember to call `pdflatex -shell-escape`, because `zhmakeindex` is not in the list of programs allowed in restricted shell-escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message means that you didn't apply “execute” permissions to the binary file.

From your terminal issue

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /Library/TeX/texbin/zhmakeindex
```

and you'll be OK, so long as you call `xelatex` (or other engine) with the `-shell-escape` option (because `zhmakeindex` is not in the allowed list for the restricted shell-escape).

<sub>Quite likely, macOS will reject the first attempt to run the program. Do as usual when you trust the source: Security settings panel in System Preferences, click “Allow anyway” and rerun, clicking “Open” at the next pop-up window.</sub>

Comment: After install the latest Go programming language and issue the codes as above, it works! Thanks very much!